# Remove the bottom border of a div table

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, border, css-tables

I'm trying to display some images in a div table, but I keep getting the border on the bottom of each image.  It's about 2-5 pixels.

I'd send an image, but I'm a new user.

I want to remove this border.

The image is 52 x 10 exactly.

I'm only in IE8 for this app.

*edit*: I'm doing a larger layout- I just boiled the code down to the single problem I'm having, which is the border at the bottom of the table.

```
/*tables*/
.WorkFlowTableStyleA
{
    display: table;
    width: 10px; 
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-style: none;  
}


/*rows*/
.WorkflowRowStyleA
{
    display: table-row;
    height: 52px;

}

/*arrow containers*/
.WorkflowCellArrowHolderA
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10px ;
}


<div class="WorkFlowTableStyleA">   
<div class="WorkflowRowStyleA">
<div class="WorkflowCellArrowHolderA" style="background-color: Black;">
<img src="../../Images/Flowchart/spacerTestTenByFiftyTwo.png" />

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="WorkFlowTableStyleA">   
<div class="WorkflowRowStyleA">
<div class="WorkflowCellArrowHolderA" style="background-color: Black;">
<img src="../../Images/Flowchart/spacerTestTenByFiftyTwo.png" />

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't say this with certainty, but it might just be the black background color in the <div> around your image. Have you tried it without the line: style="background-color: Black;" ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I've definitely tried it without the 'background-color', still get the space between the tables.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816343/why-will-this-div-img-not-center-in-ie8 I'm the junior dev here, the other dev had commented standards mode out for reasons she couldn't quite articulate. Everything works now. Thanks for the help, gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

MadHenchbot is on the money with where the "border" is coming from. It's not a border it's unfilled space in your div. (Change to style="background-color: Red") to verify that.

Good news is, since it sounds like the images are the size you want them already I think there's a quick fix:

```
/*tables*/
.WorkFlowTableStyleA
{
    display: table;
    /* get rid of width: 10px; */
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-style: none;   
}


/*rows*/
.WorkflowRowStyleA
{
    /* get rid of display: table-row; */
    height: 52px;
}

/*arrow containers*/
.WorkflowCellArrowHolderA
{
    /* get rid of display: table-cell; */
    /* get rid of width: 10px; */
    height: 52px;                             <--- Add this to set the div height.
}
```

That did the trick for me. You may have to put width back in, but I'm guessing it's unnecessary. Also, unless you're building a layout I'm not sure why you need all the table/div stuff... It looks like it's just complicating things?

Comment: Thanks for the stab. It *is* a layout, but I did not post the whole table. Instead of having my first post on stackoverflow be a huge mountain of code- I figured I'd boil it down to the fundamental.  And the fundamental problem is that when I do this table, I get a border at the bottom.

Comment: Fair enough! Just checking. :-) But I take it ^ didn't work for you? Same problem or a variation? If it's still an issue - do you have the image online anywhere so we can work with the real thing? (NBD if no.)