# How to completely remove table borders for IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I've got a website that has lots of table cells on it. 
So the table borders has to be removed from the table.

I did manage to remove the table borders for FireFox and Chrome. 
But on IE8 the table borders are still showing.

I tried to target IE8 only but still the borders are displaying for IE8.
Is there another way I can use to completely remove these borders for IE8

I tried using:

```
    border: 0px solid; |
    border-style: none; |
    style="border: 0px;" |
```

This is how it suppose to look:
[image]

And this is how this suppose to show on IE8:
[image]

Comment: Check out [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14247358/1401094)

Comment: you have to identify which borders are showing. could be the one of your table or the ones of your td's ... and the CSS you posted isn't showing... And it could even be something else, you should do a fiddle or check with code inspector

Comment: can you paste your code

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that its not the borders of the tables, IE8 is aligning your tables a bit differently than chrome or firefox.
try adding the following on top of your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try border="0" in the HTML code for the table.