# <center> tag does not work in IE

Tags: html, css

The issue is to align the image at the center of the div. This is working properly in chrome, except for IE

```
<DIV id="content"><P>Internal resources </P>
 <DIV class="containertop">
   <P>External resources </P> 
 </DIV>
 <DIV class="contentcontainer">
 <DIV class="containerImg">
    <img height="286" width="381" src="http://www.bestwestern.com/img/bg-groups-meetings.png" /alt="Banner Image" title="Banner Image"></img>

</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

CSS:

```
 .containerImg Img { 
   border: 0 none;
   padding: 0px !important;
   margin: 0px;
   width: 368px;
   height: 277px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block;
}

#content .contentcontainer { 
float:left;
padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
margin: 1px 0 0 0px;
}

#content .containertop {
padding-top: 15px;
color: #999;
}

div#content {
 font: normal 12px/1.6em arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #666;
 width: 471px;
 padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #fff !important;
 min-height: 100% !important;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

I removed  tag and tried above CSS and that is also not working.

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nf5hghqy/10/ (Open in IE)

Can we resolve this?

Comment: `<center>` tag is deprecated, you should **not** be using it at all, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html). Use CSS instead to center your divs and images.

Comment: which IE version are you using ?

Comment: I just tried your example in IE11 and the image is centered.

Comment: The `<img>` tag is self closing you don't need `</img>`, use like so: `<img src="my-image.jpg">`. The image is centered in IE for me.

Comment: Updated your fiddle a little bit. Works fine in Chrome and IE: https://jsfiddle.net/nf5hghqy/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<center>` tag is deprecated (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center))

> This tag has been deprecated in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1) in favor of the
>   CSS text-align property, which can be applied to the  element or
>   to an individual
>
> . For centering blocks, use other CSS properties
>   like margin-left and margin-right and set them to auto (or set margin
>   to 0 auto).

To get `img` aligned center you have to set it `display:block` ( because `img` is by default an `inline` element) and `margin:auto`

Another mistake, `img` is a self-closing tag, so you **can't** do this `<img></img>`

**See snippet below:**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red /*demo purposes */
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerImg">
  <img src="http://www.bestwestern.com/img/bg-groups-meetings.png" alt="Banner Image" title="Banner Image" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE** - Based on OP's new fiddle:

your issue is here:

```css
#content .contentcontainer { 
  float:left;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0px;
}
```

simply remove `float:left`, like this:

```css
#content .contentcontainer { 
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
  margin: 1px 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: I have just replicated what you have mentioned above. Yet it is not at the center

Comment: Did you Run the code snippet? Its working in the snippet so if you replicated and it is not working, you may have some CSS overridden this small piece of code.

Comment: Looks like its working in the fiddle, but not in my application. :(. Thank you

Comment: Same explanation I gave you before, it could be an overriden CSS. Better if you could show the entire code at this point, maybe the link.

Comment: Dont mind, I cannot post my code here. It will violate the security. This will be the accepted answer anyway. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

First check you have added **doctype** 
center tag doesn't work in IE ,you can use CSS as  `text-align: center` , and `auto` for **margin** , then it will work ok in IE. Fine more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816343/why-will-this-div-img-not-center-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block:

```
.containerImg img{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

The important part is to make sure the image is a block element; this way it has width. The margin-left and margin-right set to auto automatically set margins based on the width of the block element image, making the image center itself.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
.containerImg img{
     margin:auto;
     display:block
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to remove the  tags and add some css either as separate file or in line and use margin:auto; instead of your margin-left and margin-right

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` are just fine. OP does not need to use the shorthand `margin: auto`. All that does is set the top, right, bottom and left margin to `auto` all at once.

Comment: While this does help to explain what the OP needs to do, it's formatted more as a comment rather than an answer. In addition, there's nothing wrong with using `margin-left: auto; ` and `margin-right: auto;` though as you note, it could be combined into a simplier `margin: 0 auto;`.